# Prove $\left({a^n\over n!}\right)^2={1\over 2\pi i}\int_C{a^ne^{a\xi}\over{n!\xi ^n}}{d\xi \over\xi}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Note: The question had a typo and is now fixed.

I have this question from past exams.

Use the Cauchy Integral formula to prove
$$\left({a^n\over n!}\right)^2={1\over 2\pi i}\int_C{a^ne^{a\xi}\over{n!\xi ^n}}{d\xi \over\xi}$$

I have spent some time playing with it but with no luck. Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not correct, it should be $\left(\frac{a^n}{n!}\right)^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I checked, it is 'a'. But it is very likely a misprint, let me try again then.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo or mistake in the exam question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be assuming that $a\in \Bbb R$.

Let $n\in \Bbb N_0$.

Define $f_a\colon\Bbb C\to \Bbb C, z\mapsto e^{az}$.

Note that $(\forall z\in \Bbb C)\left(f_a^{(n)}(z)=a^ne^{az}\right)$, therefore $f_a^{(n)}(0)=a^n$.

Since $\displaystyle e^{az}=\sum \limits _{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\dfrac{a^n}{n!}z^n\right)$, it follows that $\displaystyle f_a(z)=\sum \limits _{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\dfrac {f_a^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n\right)$, for all $z\in \Bbb C$.

On the other hand $\displaystyle \dfrac{f_a^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int \limits_\gamma \dfrac{e^{az}}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm dz$, ([Taylor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_complex_analysis)), where $\gamma$ is some positively parametrized circle centered in $0$ going around just once.

Therefore $\displaystyle \dfrac{a^n}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int \limits_\gamma \dfrac{e^{az}}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm dz$. Multiplying by $\dfrac{a^n}{n!}$ on both sides of the equality yields the desired result.

Comment: Is it OK? ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I used Taylor series ${e^{az}\over{z^{n+1}}}=\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}{{a^iz^i}\over{z^{n+1}}}$ and get what I want.

Comment: @njguliyev Thank you. Your edit was great.

Comment: @BigTree No problem.